Unity ECS - How to modify the element of a DynamicBuffer
I have this piece of code:
foreach (DynamicBuffer<Items> items in SystemAPI.Query<DynamicBuffer<Items>>())
{
   ...
}

I am trying to modify a specific element of items. This is how I am trying to achieve this:
items[3] = modifiedItem;
But I get the error

Cannot modify members of 'items' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'.

How can I modify the elements of items?

Type DynamicBuffer<T> is a valuetype, usually it is meaningless to modify the foreach iteration variable of valuetype, so it's forbidden in C#. You can assign this variable to another variable to bypass this layer of restriction:
foreach (DynamicBuffer<Items> items in SystemAPI.Query<DynamicBuffer<Items>>())
{
   var items2 = items;
   items2[3] = modifiedItem;
}

